# State of the art post-mortem debugging for Plone

Tags: plone, pdb

What's the recommended method for invoking pdb / ipdb on certain exceptions in Plone?

The most common use case would to

- Turn on pdb on exception behavior temporary
- Make sure pdb is only invoked for certain exceptions (UnicodeDecodeError...)

What add-ons, WSGI solutions, etc. for such debugging?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done any Plone development in about a year, but [Products.PDBDebugMode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.PDBDebugMode/) used to be *the greatest thing ever*. When running in foreground mode, it would drop into PDB when an unhandled exception occurred.

Comment: Yes, but even in debug mode you don't want to see pdb under all circumstance....PDBDebugMode can be annoying if used blindly

Comment: Also does it support Plone 4?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa It should. Having filter ... is not a real need I believe, what you want is to manage to understand what happens during dev. So far enough this one is for you.